# Qt WebEngine not linking with Qt 5.12 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, dbus

I am trying to build my Qt application and I'm getting the following linking error:

> /opt/Qt5.12.2/5.12.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so: undefined reference to 'dbus_bus_register@LIBDBUS_1_3'
>
> /opt/Qt5.12.2/5.12.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so: undefined reference to 'dbus_watch_get_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
>
> etc etc

I am using Qt 5.12.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 which I know is a mismatch. If there's any workaround or a fix please let me know all my options.

Comment: try with: `sudo apt-get install libdbus`

Comment: I tried to install 'libdbus' and it said unable to locate package. Then I did an 'apt-cache search libdbus' and all I found 'libdbus-1-3' saying it's already the newest version. Which DBUS is Qt 5.12.2 compatible with if you know? Is there a way I could just download the static library of dbus?

Comment: Did anyone find a workaround for this? I tried `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libdus`, which told me that I have the latest version available.

Comment: @scap3y Thanks for following up. So the underlying issue is that Ubuntu 14.04 doesn’t support past Qt 5.8. Otherwise you run into issues like this. I moved back from 5.12 and 5.8 and all is well.

Comment: Damn, my project has components that rely on 5.10+. Anyway, guess I will try to compile from scratch. This probably the only solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Qt 5.12 Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty is not supported anymore: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72507
Qt 5.11 is working fine.